# Cannot receive value of isolated scope in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created this directive

```
angular.module('panel')
            .directive('sigPanel', sigPanel)

    function sigPanel() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope:{
                imgData:"="
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/widgets/signature/signature.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(scope.imgData);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the templateURL:

```
<canvas style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

And added this into the HTML:

```
<sig-panel imgData="test"></sig-panel>
```

The console log only outputs "undefined", shouldn't it log "test"? I know the directive html tag is working properly because the canvas appears on the page, but why won't the directive pick up the value of "imgData"?

If I try setting the scope.imgData inside the directive I get the error

```
[$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'signaturePanel' is non-assignable!
```

Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Try `<sig-panel img-data="test"></sig-panel>`, see [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for attribute normalization

Comment: `<sig-panel img-data="test"></sig-panel>` means pass the variable named 'test' (which in this case is undefined) into imgData. It looks like you want to pass a string instead: `<sig-panel img-data="'test'"></sig-panel>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `imgData` (camelCase normalized) to `img-data` (dash-delimited). Also if you want to pass the string "test" to the scope you need to put quotes around it.

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('sigPanel', sigPanel);

function sigPanel() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      imgData: "="
    },
    template: '<canvas style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.imgData);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>

  <sig-panel img-data="'test'"></sig-panel>

</div>
```

---

**assignable example:**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = 'test';
})
.directive('sigPanel', sigPanel);

function sigPanel() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      imgData: "="
    },
    template: '<canvas style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.imgData);
      scope.imgData = 'bob';
      console.log(scope.imgData);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myController'>
  <sig-panel img-data="test"></sig-panel>
  {{ test }}
</div>
```

Comment: This fixes the problem with console.log not working. But now when I try to change the scope to something different I get the error `Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression ''test'' used with directive 'signaturePanel' is non-assignable!`

Comment: "This error occurs when a directive defines an isolate scope property (using the = mode in the scope option of a directive definition) but the directive is used with an expression that is not-assignable." The string "test" is non-assignable. If you use a variable you wont see that error. Not much more I can provide without more context of what you are trying to do.